# Navigation.PushAsync doesn't work in ContentView?

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I have a `ContentView`. A `TapGestureRecognizer` has been added to it. A page should be pushed if it's tapped. I did something like this:

```
var tapRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
tapRecognizer.Tapped += async (_, _) => await Navigation.PushAsync(new GalleryPage());
GestureRecognizers.Add(tapRecognizer);
```

But it does not work as expected.

The app is using `Shell`. It works if I use `Shell` style navigation.As the docs suggests, `Navigation` works in a Shell app. And it do work if I call it in an `Page`.

So I can't call `Navigation.PushAsync` in a `ContentView` ? What's the correct way do this?

The ContentView:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="....GalleryThumbnailView"
             BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Thumbnail}">
    <Frame CornerRadius="6">
        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <Image Aspect="AspectFit" HeightRequest="256" WidthRequest="256" Source="{Binding CoverUrl}"/>
            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding Category}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding PublishedTime}"/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </Frame>
</ContentView>
```

The page holds the views:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:...Views"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:...Models"
             x:Class="...Pages.HomePage"
             Title="..." Loaded="OnLoaded">
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding Latest}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <views:GalleryThumbnailView Thumbnail="{Binding Source={x:RelativeSource AncestorType={Type models:GalleryThumbnail}}}" />
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

The page I'm trying to navigate to:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="...Pages.GalleryPage"
             Title="GalleryPage">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="{Binding GalleryThumbnail.Title}"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <Image HeightRequest="256" WidthRequest="256" Source="{Binding GalleryThumbnail.CoverUrl}"/>
            <VerticalStackLayout>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Please show more relevant code about xaml.

Comment: `Navigation` is a property on page types - `ContentView` does not have one.  To navigate from a `ContentView` you need to get a reference to the currently active page

Comment: @Jason I don't know if it works as expected but I do believe ( at least in MAUI ) that there is a `Navigation` property on `ContentView` (inherited from NavigatableElement).

Comment: Yes I can confirm there's a ```Navigation```  and can work well in ContentView as I have made a small demo. But your case seems more complicated and perhaps with other questions. So I would appreciate it if you could show more code. Thanks.

Comment: And you said you can't call Navigation.PushAsync in a ContentView. So how you add GestureRecognizer for ContentView in code behind?  Because we cannot get the control in  DataTemplate from code behind.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT I can call it without any problems but it does not work. It doesn't push the page. The code where I add GestureRecognizer is in the first code block. It's in the ContentView's constructor right after the InitializeComponent. I can confirm that the lambda is called but the page is not pushed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a workaround:

```
 tapRecognizer.Tapped += async (_, _) => await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new GalleryPage());
```

Hope it works.

Comment: It works. But does it only works on the root page? What if the ContentView is not on the root page?

Comment: Yes, it also works if you put the ContentView in the second page or third page.

Comment: But why not add the GestureRecognizer in ContentPage xaml instead of ContentView constructor?

Comment: Well I suppose it make more sense to do that in ContentView considering it's the ContentView that responds to the gesture.